# How does a Spark Application work?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to implement a simple Spark SQL Application that takes a query as input and processes the data. But because I need to cache the data and I have to maintain a single SQL Context object. I am not able to understand how I can use same SQL context and keep getting queries from user.

So how does an application work? When an application is submitted to cluster, does it keep running on the cluster or performs a specific task and shuts down immediately after the task?

Answer (score 1):

Spark application has a driver program that starts and configures the Spark Context. Driver program can be inside your application and you can use the same Spark Context throughout the life of your application.

Spark Context is thread safe, so multiple users can use it to run jobs concurrently.

There is an open source project [Zeppelin](http://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/) that does just that.